# how to change the nested subdocument field status to true or false

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to change a specific nested sub document field in the document status to  true  or  false,

I know my schema is more nested but i don't have any other option

this is my document model

```
{
"_id":"63b3b4024"
"name":"dev"
"email":"dev@gmail.com"
"image":"https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com"

"tickets":[
{
"sid":"63b3f5768"
"eid":"63b3f5777"
user_name:"john"
event_name:"workshop"
status:false
_id:{
"$oid":"63b4178c4"
}
},
{
"sid":"63b3f5769"
"eid":"63b3f5778"
"user_name":"john"
"event_name":"workshop"
"status":false
"_id":{
"$oid":"63b4178c5"
}
{
"sid":"63b3f5770"
"eid":"63b3f5779"
"user_name":"john"
"event_name":"workshop"
"status":false
"_id":{
"$oid":"63b4178c6"
}
{
"sid":"63b3f5771"
"eid":"63b3f5780"
"user_name":"john"
"event_name":"workshop"
"status":false
"_id":{
"$oid":"63b4178c7"
}
""__v":0
}]
```

I need to change tickests.status to true or false.How to check this field?

Can anyone suggest me the exact query to find this?

Specification

- node: v14.17.3,
- mongoose: "^6.6.5",
- mongodb:Atlas

Comment: Do you want to update all of the items in `tickets` array?

Answer (score 0):

you can use arrayFilters to identify the ticket you want to change the status of and use an update method as:

```
await Collection.updateOne(
  { _id: collectionId },
  {
    $set: {
      "tickets.$[ticket].status": false,
    },
  },
  { arrayFilters: [{ "ticket._id": ticketId }] }
);
```

here, you identify the ticket you want by specifying the id in the arrayFilters as ticket._id, and you access this ticket in $set. Then, you change the status or any other field as required.